# Create war file with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, war

I have an issue when I compile my project using Maven. Below there is the images of the structure of my project. When I decompile it, I see its made it in a wrong way. The .war file, misses all of the jsp contained in pages folder, the js, and the style. When I build the project says it's builde successfull but its not. There is an image of the decompiled project and my pom.xml.
How can I correct this?

[image]

[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>name</groupId>
<artifactId>name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!--  <webXml>WebRoot\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml> -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why do you make it yourself so hard to change the default (standard) maven directory structure? Keep it simple, use the defaults, only change the default if there is a really really good reason to change it. 
Now it's not included because Maven cannot find the (re)sources.

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this. I used the convert to maven option. This was not a maven project. How can I resolve this?? Looking for the default maven structure and copy paste my classes?

Comment: No problem. We all have to learn new things. The best you can do is to create a new maven project with the default directory structure and copy/move the sources and resources to the correct locations inside of that structure.

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I'm gonna try it, thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'decompile'? you can inspect the contents of a war/jar with `jar -tvf /srv/tomcat/webapps/demo.war`.